What's the JSON format for the Transaction Builder?
I'm trying to uploading a JSON file to the Transaction Builder but I keep getting parsing error. What's the expected format?
I'm talking about this drag&drop:

The only doc I found is https://help.safe.global/en/articles/234052-transaction-builder but it does not mention any format

You can get an idea about the format of the Transactions Batch JSON from this post.
Moreover, you can generate and download the Transactions Batch JSON file if you've the contract address and ABI.
As, in my case, I've downloaded this Transactions Batch.json file for the deposit function:
{
    "version": "1.0",
    "chainId": "1",
    "createdAt": 1731063959080,
    "meta": {
        "name": "Transactions Batch",
        "description": "",
        "txBuilderVersion": "1.17.1",
        "createdFromSafeAddress": "0xfF501B324DC6d78dC9F983f140B9211c3EdB4dc7",
        "createdFromOwnerAddress": "",
        "checksum": "0xbe796761ef9e98c9b4eedf8ceb96feed7cf41f9728ef8925d18eee15b718a1ba"
    },
    "transactions": [
        {
            "to": "0xfFf9976782d46CC05630D1f6eBAb18b2324d6B14",
            "value": "100000000000000000",
            "data": null,
            "contractMethod": {
                "inputs": [],
                "name": "deposit",
                "payable": true
            },
            "contractInputsValues": null
        }
    ]
}

By using the WETH contract address (on Ethereum Sepolia) and ABI.




I would recommend importing contracts using their address to get a better understanding of the data, format and how the transaction builder works. The example described above is a good one but in order to help with this would be great to get a little more context on what you are trying to do and the exact error message received.
